# Cómo crear una lista con enlaces al detalle usando Django REST Framework

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Estoy usando [djangorestframework](/questions/tagged/djangorestframework) versión 3.4 con [django](/questions/tagged/django) 1.10 para crear una API con **HyperlinkedModelSerializer** y **ModelViewSet** pero quiero que el `id` o `pk` de la lista contenga el enlace al detalle, **pero no ocurre así**.

Este es mi archivo `serializers.py`

```
class PolicySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Policy
        fields = ('pk', 'revision', 'pub_date', 'contenido', 'contenido_html',
                  'cambios', 'cambios_html', 'notify', 'URI', 'data', 'autor')
```

Y este es el archivo `views.py`:

```
class PolicyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly, )
    queryset = Policy.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PolicySerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
```

En mi archivo de rutas, uso `DefaultRouter()` para que DRF se encargue de todo:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'policies', PolicyViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    # ... otras rutas aquí
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
    # ... unas cuantas rutas más

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

El resultado de esto es com sigue:

```
(cmi) \proyectos\cmi\server [policy-links#13 ≡]> http http://localhost:8000/api/v1/policies/
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 05 Aug 2016 15:46:45 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3
Vary: Accept
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "autor": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/dc7e06ee-d2a5-4e88-ae01-cd6dcde33764/",
            // "otros campos": "Campos no relevantes para la pregunta",
            "pk": "70190959-20af-445e-ba85-cd89fd6dabc9",
        },
        {
            "autor": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/dc7e06ee-d2a5-4e88-ae01-cd6dcde33764/",
            // "otros campos": "Campos no relevantes para la pregunta",
            "pk": "1c0ed5aa-6a01-47ff-8bff-2b3e6e72172d",
        }
    ]
}
```

Como puede observarse, el campo `autor` tiene un URI al *endpoint* de la API de usuarios, lo cual es correcto, pero *además*, necesito que el campo `pk` tenga un enlace al detalle de la política.

### Resultado esperado

El resultado esperado es obtener para el campo `pk` una URI al detalle de dicha política, que es de la siguiente forma:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/policies/1c0ed5aa-6a01-47ff-8bff-2b3e6e72172d/
```

Por cierto, ya que estoy usando ModelViewSet, el enlace funciona como se espera:

```
\cmi\server [policy-links#13 ≡ +0 ~2 -0 !]> http http://localhost:8000/api/v1/policies/1c0ed5aa-6a01-47ff-8bff-2b3e6e72172d/
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 05 Aug 2016 15:53:51 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3
Vary: Accept
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

{
    "URI": "",
    "autor": "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/dc7e06ee-d2a5-4e88-ae01-cd6dcde33764/",
    "cambios": "Versión inicial",
    "cambios_html": "<p>Versión inicial</p>",
    "contenido": "No por mucho __madrugar__ amanece más *temprano*",
    "contenido_html": "<p>No por mucho <strong>madrugar</strong> amanece más <em>temprano</em></p>",
    "data": {
        "aprobo": "Dr. Marcos",
        "elaboro": [
            {
                "nombre": "Lupita"
            }
        ],
        "reviso": "Hugo"
    },
    "notify": false,
    "pk": "1c0ed5aa-6a01-47ff-8bff-2b3e6e72172d",
    "pub_date": "2011-09-01",
    "revision": 0
}
```

Solo necesito que aparezca el URL del detalle en el campo `pk`.

Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se debe usar una relación *serializada*, ya sea indicando el campo que contiene la relación o creando una propiedad nueva que presente la relación.

### Indicando el campo

Se especifican las características del campo relacionado en el serializador y **se enlista** en el parámetro `fields`.

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Conjunto, Area

```
class ConjuntoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Conjunto
fields = '__all__'
```

> La documentación para el campo `PrimeryKeyRelatedField` se encuentra en este [enlace](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield).

### Creando una propiedad nueva

Se crea una propiedad nueva en el serializer y se agrega en el parámetro `fields`.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Puesto, Curso, Persona


class PuestoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Puesto
        fields = ('id', 'clave', 'nombre', 'orden')


class PersonaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    puesto_nombre = PuestoSerializer(read_only=True, source='puesto')
    class Meta:
        model = Persona
        fields = (
            'rfc', 'nombrecompleto', 'genero', 'puesto', 'puesto_nombre',
            'alcance', 'fecha_ingreso', 'activo'
)
```

En este caso, el tipo de campo se refiere **a otro serializador** y debe indicarse el campo **fuente** que crea la relación en el parámetro `source`.